# Django data migration - worked, but far from performant

Tags: python, database, django

Background: I am learning web dev and decided on the Django framework as an excuse to learn Python at the same time. (Background is stats with lots of `R` and `C++`).

I wrote a Django app to assist with a popular word guessing game. There is a very simple model:

```py
from django.db import models

class FiveLetterWord(models.Model):
    Word = models.CharField(max_length=5,unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Word
```

and I populated this using a fixture. This was generated by loading a large number of five letter words from various sources, deduplicating, etc. (I am now aware that the game has its list available; I used a bunch of free dictionary files instead).

Alls well. Apart from the fact that my deduplication turned out to be case sensitive. That is, it had `Aaron` and `aaron` in it. Some few words were in triplicate e.g. `AARON` as well. I only wanted one of these. (Sorry anyone called Aaron reading this). The views and template use case insensitive logic so which one does not matter.

I wrote the following data migration to identify duplicate entries and remove them.

```py
from django.db import migrations
from django.db.models.functions import Lower

def remove_duplicate_rows(apps, scheme_editor):
    FiveLetterWord = apps.get_model('my_app', 'FiveLetterWord')

    l_qset = FiveLetterWord.objects.annotate(lWord=Lower('Word'))

    distinct_word_list = list(l_qset.values_list('lWord',flat=True).distinct().order_by('lWord'))

    distinct_word_dict = { i : l_qset.filter(lWord__exact = i).count() for i in distinct_word_list }

    dupe_dict = { k:v for k,v in distinct_word_dict.items() if v > 1 }

    dupe_pk = { k : list(l_qset.filter(lWord__exact = k).values_list('id',flat = True)[1:])
                for k in dupe_dict.keys() }

    pk_kill = [item for sublist in dupe_pk.values() for item in sublist]

    for pk in pk_kill:
        kill_me = l_qset.get(pk=pk)
        kill_me.delete()

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('cheatle', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(remove_duplicate_rows)
    ]
```

This worked, in that only `Aaron` was left. But it took of the order of tens of seconds to run (c. 12k records left at the end). From my experience writing `SQL` I would have expected this to run on the order of a second at most. I mean it's fine as a one off thing for tens of thousands of records, but I feel it won't scale to millions of rows if I ever screw up like that.

1. Could this be made more efficient?
2. Could this be made more efficient using only idiomatic ORM functionality? (i.e., not just typing out a SQL string and passing it to the DB)